Gitlab Pipeline fails finding secure file in container
I currently have a Gitlab pipeline that is running the following node.JS code
const options = {
  hostname: 'test.test.test.com',
  port,
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.env.CERT_PATH, '/'+process.env.CERT_NAME+'.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.env.CERT_PATH, '/'+process.env.CERT_NAME+'.crt')),
};

It is failing while trying to access a secure file I uploaded, call it TEST.key and TEST.crt to the project saying it does not exist. I assume the problem is my code is not seeing the right directory for the file(s) but I can't seem to understand where this code is looking.
My .gitlab-ci.yml file is failing on this section
test_job:
  stage: test
  only:
    - dev
    - test
    - main
  # Allow the use of Node Package Manager: Grabs the latest version of Node
  image: node:16.15.1
  variables:
    SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: '/etc/ssl/certs/'
  script:
    - echo "Downloading necessary files..."
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
    - echo "Testing Application..."
    - npm test
    - echo "Done!"

Here is the log from the pipeline
$ echo "Downloading necessary files..."
Downloading necessary files...
$ curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
Downloading download-secure-files from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/releases/permalink/latest/downloads/download-secure-files-linux-amd64
Installing download-secure-files at /usr/bin/download-secure-files
Downloading Secure Files (v0.1.12) to /builds/axxxx/myApp/etc/ssl/certs
TEST.crt downloaded to /etc/ssl/certs/TEST.crt
TEST.key downloaded to /etc/ssl/certs/TEST.key
$ ls -alrth /etc/ssl/certs/TEST.key
ls: cannot access '/etc/ssl/certs/TEST.key': No such file or directory

